# MySQL index not being used at all

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm using MySQL 5.1.73 (FreePBX), and our cdr (call log) table has stopped using its indexes. The strange thing is that if I duplicate the table, and populate it with the existing cdr data, the indexes **are** used in the copy:

```
mysql> explain select * from cdr where calldate='2013-01-24 15:27:19'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: cdr
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1391088
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `cdr_copy` (
    ->   `calldate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    ->   `clid` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `src` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `dst` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `dcontext` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `channel` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `dstchannel` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `lastapp` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `lastdata` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `duration` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `billsec` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `disposition` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `amaflags` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ->   `accountcode` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `uniqueid` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `userfield` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `did` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `recordingfile` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `cnum` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `cnam` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `outbound_cnum` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `outbound_cnam` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   `dst_cnam` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ->   KEY `calldate` (`calldate`),
    ->   KEY `dst` (`dst`),
    ->   KEY `accountcode` (`accountcode`),
    ->   KEY `uniqueid` (`uniqueid`)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into cdr_copy select * from cdr;
Query OK, 1391093 rows affected (33.59 sec)
Records: 1391093  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain select * from cdr_copy where calldate='2013-01-24 15:27:19'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: cdr_copy
         type: ref
possible_keys: calldate
          key: calldate
      key_len: 8
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've checked the **cdr** table, and it seems to say that everything is OK. Obviously the *easy* method would be just to dump the table, and recreate it during some down time. However that seems like a bit of bodge, because I don't like not knowing what actual issue is.

Comment: Are you sure the index hasn't been dropped (`DESCRIBE cdr_copy`)?

Comment: How long does the specific-time query you mentioned take to run (not explain, but run)? If the query's fast maybe there's a difference between what explain says and what the server is doing.  Have you tried `REPAIR TABLE?` That will emit diagnostics.

Comment: @MrMarchello - the query on cdr_copy is using the index, not the other way round.

Comment: @OllieJones - the query using the index takes 0.00s (less than the precision of the CLI client), whereas without the index it takes 1.83s
When using a between clause, indexed is 0.02s vs 2.11s
I've attempted a quick repair, but that made no difference. I'll have to attempt a full repair when the server isn't in use.

Comment: So, an extended repair made no difference and had no complaints, so I just dropped and re-created the indexes. And my queries are now using the indexes. Still would like to know why.

Comment: @oobayly My mistake, I meant `DESCRIBE cdr` (before you dropped and added the indexes)

Comment: @MrMarchello - Unfortunately I didn't check the out output of DESCRIBE, however the query I used to create cdr_copy was take from SHOW CREATE TABLE cdr. The question is, would SHOW CREATE show indexes, while DESCRIBE doesn't?

I had *assumed* that the indexes would be present if they were in SHOW CREATE TABLE. Also, I received no errors when I did drop the index, so I *have to assume* that the indexes were indeed present.

Comment: @oobayly `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would have shown the indexes, it was just a thought. Curious case, but I guess we'll never know now ;)